# CSV file formatting in Email Class

Tags: apex, trigger, singleemailmessage

I am creating csv file and attaching that using `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage`.

There are two problems

1. In my CSV i am not getting header, though i have written code for csv header
2. CSV file is showing some duplicate values in the same row.

Please find the attached image for the mentioned queries
[image]

Also find the code here

```
for(LOC_Localization_Request__c objLocRequest : ListValidLOCRequest){
                if(MapLRAssets.containsKey(objLocRequest.id)){
                    String Subject = '';
                    List<LOC_LR_Asset__c> LRAssets = MapLRAssets.get(objLocRequest.id);
                    LOC_Contact__c objContact = MapContacts.get(objLocRequest.Ordering_Representative1__c);

                    lstEmailValues.add(objContact.LOC_Email__c);

                    if(objLocRequest.LOC_Localization_Project__c != null){
                        //system.debug('MapUser===>'+MapUser.get(objLocRequest.LOC_Localization_Project__r.Manufacturing_Representative__c));
                        String ccEmail = MapUser.get(objLocRequest.LOC_Localization_Project__c);
                        //system.debug('User=====>'+objUser);
                        lstCCEmailValues.add(ccEmail);
                    }

                    string header = 'LR Number,Title,Language,Deliverable Type,Description\n';
                    string finalstr = header ;
                    String body = header;  

                    String htmlBody = '';
                    htmlBody = '<table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse"><caption>Deliverables Under Completed LR</caption><tr><th>LR#</th><th>Title</th><th>Language</th><th>Deliverable Type</th><th>Description</th></tr>';   


                    if(objLocRequest.LR_OMS_Identifier__c != null) finalstr = objLocRequest.LR_OMS_Identifier__c+',';
                    else finalstr = objLocRequest.Name+',';  


                    for(LOC_LR_Asset__c objLR : LRAssets){

                         String records = objLR.Localization_Request__r.Name+','+objLR.Asset__r.Title_Version__r.FOX_ID__r.Name+','+objLR.Asset__r.Language_Description__c+','+objLR.Asset__r.Deliverable_Type__c+','+objLR.Asset__r.Long_Description__c+'\n';
                         finalstr = finalstr + records;
                         htmlBody += '<tr><td>' + objLR.Localization_Request__r.Name + '</td><td>' + objLR.Asset__r.Title_Version__r.FOX_ID__r.Name + '</td><td>'+objLR.Asset__r.Language_Description__c+'</td><td>'+objLR.Asset__r.Deliverable_Type__c+'</td><td>'+objLR.Asset__r.Long_Description__c+'</td></tr>';

                    }

                    EmailTemplate et = etList.get(0);
                    //lstEmailValues = Localization_Utility.getActualEmailIds(lstEmailValues);
                    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email =new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                    Messaging.EmailFileAttachment csvAttc = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
                    system.debug('finalstr====>'+finalstr);
                    blob csvBlob = Blob.valueOf(finalstr);
                    string csvname= 'CompletedLR.csv';
                    csvAttc.setFileName(csvname);
                    csvAttc.setBody(csvBlob);

                    //String[] toAddresses = new list<string> {'test@test.com'};

                    if(objLocRequest.LR_OMS_Identifier__c != null) Subject = objLocRequest.LR_OMS_Identifier__c+' is completed';
                    else Subject = objLocRequest.Name+' is completed';
                    email.setSubject(subject);
                    email.setToAddresses(lstEmailValues);
                    if(!lstCCEmailValues.isEmpty())email.setCcAddresses(lstCCEmailValues);
                    if(LRAssets.size() <= Integer.valueOf(AssetListSize)) email.setHtmlBody(htmlBody);  
                    else email.setPlainTextBody('Please find the attached sheet for the Completed Deliverables');
                    email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[]{csvAttc});
                    lstEmails.add(email);

                }
            }

                if(!lstEmails.isEmpty()) Messaging.sendEmail(lstEmails);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your header is lost is in this code fragment

```
string finalstr = header ;  // set header
String body = header;  

String htmlBody = '';
htmlBody = '<table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse"><caption>Deliverables Under Completed LR</caption><tr><th>LR#</th><th>Title</th><th>Language</th><th>Deliverable Type</th><th>Description</th></tr>';   

// smash header
if(objLocRequest.LR_OMS_Identifier__c != null) 
   finalstr = objLocRequest.LR_OMS_Identifier__c+',';
else finalstr = objLocRequest.Name+',';


...
blob csvBlob = Blob.valueOf(finalstr); // build CSV from string
string csvname= 'CompletedLR.csv';
csvAttc.setFileName(csvname);
csvAttc.setBody(csvBlob);  // set CSV body
```

I'm guessing you want this:

```
if(objLocRequest.LR_OMS_Identifier__c != null) 
   finalstr += objLocRequest.LR_OMS_Identifier__c+',';
else finalstr += objLocRequest.Name+',';
```